# Java XML SAXParser throws NullPointerException on method .parse(InputSource,XMLCommandsHandler)

Tags: java, xml, sockets, stream, saxparser

I get a very misterious NullPointerException when parsing a stream comming from a socket with jdk's javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.

My InputSource is a RecordingInputStream that I created by extending FilterInputStream in order to be able to record in a log file all the data that I receive on the socket before it goes down to the parser. By using this way I can now see, that the NullPointerException is thrown specifically when the following tag appears in the stream:

```
<order act="D" order_id="16508679" scn="147185767940" reason="DELETE_ORDR" who_id="90296"/>
```

Otherwise the parsing of the stream is working okay. All other XML tags that frequently comes, get parsed successfuly (no exceptions are thrown), and corresponding XMLCommandsHandler's methods do get invoked correctly.

Please, any clue why this NullPointerException appears? Otherwise I'm facing the alternative to curse all ready-written XML stream parsers, and write my own simple parser. Tired of exploring other software's bugs, or poor design :(

Comment: Have you attempted to reproduce the problem using just the input that you have identified?

Comment: Post your handler that is supposed to deal with this tag, and a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Sorry I forgot to post my answer back then I was realy overwhelmed with work. I remember now, and I answer it now.
It was a nullpointer exception in my code. Code that the XMLCommandsHandler is calling. Of course it had nothing to do with the SAX parser.

My appologies.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/) or [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).